# Return certain fields if a date matches

Tags: command-line, text-processing

```
2017-11-27 20:11:13,632 INFO  abc: [java: Thread-389579]: Completed executing command
2017-11-27 20:11:13,632 INFO  abc: [java: Thread-389579]: OK
2017-11-27 20:11:13,632 INFO  abc: [java: Thread-389579]: <completed>
2017-11-27 20:11:13,632 INFO  abc: [java: Thread-389579]: release for adeo/student
```

My approaches:

```
awk 'today="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" ($1 = today) && /Completed executing command/ {cnr = NR} NR == (cnr+3) {gsub(/\/.*/,"",$NF); print $NF}' filename
awk 'today="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" ($1 == today) && /Completed executing command/ { cnr = NR } NR == (cnr+3) { sub("/.*","",$NF); print $NF }' filename
```

We  want to print only `adeo` and `student` in two different variables. Condition is if $1 is equal to current date then it should search for `Completed executing command` in the entire file and then skip two lines and then print `adeo` and `student`. (The name adeo/student is not fixed it changes, so in above case we want adeo and student but if there is some other name, that should appear instead).

From our approach we are getting only `adeo`. How can we achieve this using `awk`/`sed`/`grep` or any other tool?

Comment: Its an duplicate, But i am not getting how to get that. Beginner at awk

Comment: Remove `sub("/.*","",$NF);`

Comment: It will print adeo/student. Not like name1=adeo name2=student 
currently what i did is i stored awk result in one variable and applied cut and it worked

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47488077/7552 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/407303/4667. Don't ask the same question on multple sites.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm voting to reopen this, and I urge you to do so as well. At least if the links are correct, both those other questions have been deleted. Even if they hadn't been, this has valuable answers, which have been upvoted. It just makes no sense for this to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather from the comments that you want the output to look like `name1=adeo name2=student`.  If that is the case, try:

```
$ awk -v today="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"  '$1 == today && /Completed executing command/ { cnr = NR } cnr && NR == cnr+3 {sub(/\//, " name2=", $NF); print "name1="$NF }' filename
name1=adeo name2=student
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can approach using external variables is via placing `today` into environment,and use `ENVIRON["today"]` within `awk`. Using `gsub()` is also unnecessary, if you want to just get the name and student part and if they are always going to be last item in the line.

```
$ today=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') awk '$1 = ENVIRON["today"] && /Completed executing command/ {cnr = NR} NR == (cnr+3) {print $NF}' input.txt                                
adeo/student
```